# Two IconButtons inside of InputRightElement in InputGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am working on a search component in Chakra UI. How are you supposed to fit two IconButtons inside of a single InputRightElement in an InputGroup? The second IconButton goes outside of the Input field.

```js
<InputGroup size="lg" shadow={"md"} borderRadius={"80px"}>
    <Input
        ref={searchInputRef}
        type="text"
        borderRadius={"80px"} 
        placeholder="Search" 
        defaultValue={router.query.searchInput}
    />
    <InputRightElement>
        <IconButton
            icon={<GrFormClose />}
            onClick={() => (searchInputRef.current.value = "")}
        >
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton 
            onClick={() => {} } 
            colorScheme="gray"
            aria-label="Search"
            isRound="true"
            icon={<Search2Icon />}
            size={"sm"}
            ></IconButton>
    </InputRightElement>
</InputGroup>
```

I attached an image of what it looks like:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Regarding inserting a `Divider` between the 2 `IconButton`, it seems that the `Divider` need a specified `orientation="vertical"` and a set height such as `h={6}` to work.

Tested live in here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m9qpdg?file=src/App.js)

```
<Divider orientation="vertical" h={6} borderColor="darkgray" />
```

**Original**

There could be many approaches, but a possible solution is to wrap the 2 `IconButton` in a `Stack` as the `children` of `InputRightElement`, and give it a right margin `mr` to place the icons in desired way.

The placement can be further adjusted by `spacing` and `mr` properties of the `Stack`.

Simplified example tested in here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f5bexm?file=src/App.js)

```
<InputGroup size="lg" shadow={"md"} borderRadius={"80px"}>
  <Input
    ref={searchInputRef}
    type="text"
    borderRadius={"80px"}
    placeholder="Search"
    defaultValue={router.query.searchInput}
  />
  <InputRightElement
    children={
      <HStack spacing={3} mr={16}>
        <IconButton
          icon={<GrFormClose />}
          onClick={() => (searchInputRef.current.value = "")}
        />
        <IconButton
          onClick={() => {}}
          colorScheme="gray"
          aria-label="Search"
          isRound="true"
          icon={<Search2Icon />}
          size={"sm"}
        />
      </HStack>
    }
  />
</InputGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and concise answer. 

Do you know if Dividers are able to put placed inside the Hstack to separate the two Icon Buttons? This does not seem to work.

Comment: @EnricoShippole Thanks for the reply, it seems that `Divider` works but need some specific properties set, I've updated the answer for the details.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. It was not clear to me that a height parameter needed to be set from the documentation. Do you do any consulting work at all for Front End applications?

Comment: @EnricoShippole Thanks for the comment, for me just free consulting by answering interesting questions on SO for now, if it counts 

Comment: I think  it is not fine we need to add margin right to be able to have 2+ elements in InputRightElements. Material ui can do it